# Creating new matrix from existing one

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix in Matlab, A =

```
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
10    11    12
```

Now I want to create a new matrix B derived from A. The new matrix should look like: B =

```
1   0
0   4
2   0
0   5
3   0
0   6
```

Is it possible to solve that without using FOR loop?

Comment: What is the specification for creating B? Can you give more general criteria?

Comment: if matrix A has x number of rows and y number of columns, matrix B should have (y*2) rows and 2 columns. Data from 1st row and nth column of A will be placed in (2n-1)th row and 1st column and data from 2nd row and nth column of A will be placed in 2n th row and 2nd column of B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy with some indexing:

```
A=[1     2     3  ;
   4     5     6  ;
   7     8     9  ;
   10    11    12 ];

B = zeros(2*size(A,2),2);
B(1:2:end,1)=A(1,:); % put first row values in first column of c
B(2:2:end,2)=A(2,:); % put énd row values in 2nd column of c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only working with 4x4 matrices then yes it is.

You want to convert a 4x4 and using row x column convention you can access A's elements one at at time like so `A[row][column]`

Then you want a 6x2 matrix then you just call it with zeros `B = zeros(6,2)`

Then alternate down `B[row][column] = A[row][column]` and you should be able to build it out easily.

Comment: Dimension of A is 4*n where n could be any integer number

Comment: Then obviously you'll need to use a for loop. You can use a while loop too but if you're trying to take in account a variable number of elements then you're going to need to use a method that accounts for that. To be absolutely clear, you're writing a function in the MATLAB language right?

Comment: 'Then alternate down', you're a bit too vague on how to do this without looping imo.. _and_ you're indexing looks weird (OP is looking for a matlab solution, not C or anything).